# Knowledge required to understand YOLOR

Tags: yolo, yolov5, yolov4

I'm trying to learn YOLOR but everything look like a alien language to me
so for the expert out there
What knowledge do I need to have to start learning and implement this object detection model?
Do I need to learn Yaml and Shell Command on Pycharm to run YOLOR

what I know:

- Basic python
- CNN
- Understand how YOLOR dataset labeled

Thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start using YOLOR I suggest that you begin with YOLOv5 that is easier to learn and implement. You need to know how to run Shell Command on Pycharm. Here is a simple code that you can run on Pycharm:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import cv2

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    results = model(frame)
    results.print()
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

before you run this code you need to install and import some dependencies:

1. install pytorch:

pip install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html

2. import YOLOv5: git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
3. install the requirements: cd yolov5 & pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: Thank you Chananel, I really appreciate your help,  what requirement to get start on yolov5,  I just have the basic (python, yolov5 < yolov4 but easier to implement, labeling for yolo dataset)  I'm a self-taught so I would be very appreciated if you can point out what I'm missing to get started